# Integral $\int_{A}(x+1)\mathrm dx \mathrm dy$ over $A=\{(x,y)\in R^2, y\leq 2x,y \leq -2x,y \geq x^2-3 \}$

Tags: integration

I Faced a problem to find upper and lower  bounds for integrals in examples like:

$$\int_{A}(x+1)dxdy$$ Where $A=\{(x,y)\in R^2, y\leq 2x,y \leq -2x,y \geq x^2-3 \}$;

Could you help me to understand this? Because in similar problems like

bounds for x and y looks like : $1\leq x \leq 2$,  $2\leq y \leq 3$ it is easy for me and I understood this. But above problem I can't solve. Please, be kind, to show the method how to solve that kind of problem.

Comment: First try to picture what the integration region is. Then divide it into pieces which can be easily parametrized. Also you could try to use Mathjax and write the equation yourself instead of posting a picture. This will likely come across as better etiquette and you may get more inputs.

Comment: Someone please step by step show me how to solve this/

Answer (score 1):

This is the region over you must integrate

[image]

Also, due symmetry in $0X$ axis, your integral can be written as

$$\int\int_A x+1 \,dx\,dy=2\int\int_{A'} 1 \,dx\,dy=2\int_{0}^1\int_{x^2-3}^{2x}1\,dy\,dx=2\int_{0}^1 2x-(x^2-3)\,dy=\frac{22}{3}$$

where $A'$ is the figure's right side ($x>0$).